# pgfplots custom axis scaling function

Tags: pgfplots

If I have a data set in which most of the interesting stuff happens for small values of `x` then I can use `\begin{semilogxaxis} ... \end{semilogxaxis}` to create a plot with a logarithmic `x` axis, which has the effect of compressing the plot for large `x` values and using more of the plot area for small values of `x`.

I have a data set where `0 < x < 1` and everything interesting happens for values of `x` close to 1. I would therefore like to do the opposite of a log plot: use a custom function to specify the progression along the `x` axis so that large values of `x` occupy a disproportionately large part of the plot area.

I know I could hack this by transforming the `x` values in my data and then faking custom tick labels, but is there an easy way to get pgfplots to do this automatically?

Comment: Easy way? I don’t know. There are certain keys to transform input data (here `x filter` and `x coord trafo`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In principle pgfplots provides what you need. Especially the `x coord trafo` section of the manual helps as Qrrbrbirlbel has mentioned.

Here is a very simple example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,12pt,preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{transform.dat}
1   1
2   4
3   9
4   16
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8} 
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks,calc} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotsset{
x coord trafo/.code={\pgfmathparse{#1^2}\pgfmathresult},
x coord inv trafo/.code={\pgfmathparse{#1}\pgfmathresult},
}

\begin{axis}[ylabel={$f(x)=x^2$},xlabel=$x^2$]
    \addplot table {transform.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

Here the x-axis is transformed and the final result is a straight line again:

[image]

Comment: You should use `x coord inv trafo/.code={\pgfmathparse{sqrt(#1)}\pgfmathresult}`, otherwise the tick values are wrong. Note that automatic "nice" tick selection doesn't work in this case, you'll have to set the tick values manually using something like `xtick={0,...,4}`.

Comment: This answer is a little wrong – namely the code only need to *set* `\pgfmathresult`, not *expands to* the result – so the final `\pgfmathresult` is useless.

Comment: @user202729: Ah thanks, that is indeed superfluous.