# Symlog as axis scaling in PGFPlots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis

I'm new to Ti*k*Z plotting. `:)`

I want to plot data from a CSV with [`pgfplots`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RR1vg.png) in an axis environment. 
The data has a quite large range, for which a linear y-axis isn't very appropriate. In Python's `matplotlib` is a scaling called `symlog` (for symmetric log: A mirrored log scale around the x-axis), which also allows negative values (e.g., a range from -(10^5) to 10^5)
Since `ymode=symlog` doesn't work, is there any other way to create `symlog`-like plots?

My code is equivalent to (works only for the positive values):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmode=linear,
    ymode=log,
    xlabel=$f$ (Hz),
    ylabel=$T$ (-),
    title={Measured transfer function of analogue filter},
    grid=both,
    minor grid style={gray!25},
    major grid style={gray!25},
    width=0.75\linewidth,
    no marks]
\addplot[line width=1pt,solid,color=blue] %
    coordinates {(0,-1000) (1,-100) (2,-10) (3,-1) (4,0) (5,1) (6,10) (7,100) (8,1000)};
\addlegendentry{Transfer function};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Source: https://olivierpieters.be/blog/2015/10/23/latex-plotting-from-file.html

Edit:

The result is:

[image]

But for `coordinates {(0,-1000) (1,-100) (2,-10) (3,-1) (4,0) (5,1) (6,10) (7,100) (8,1000)};` the plot should look like (the scaling between -1 and +1 is linear):

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) What should the resulting plot look like? Do you have an example image from Python?

Comment: Your `pyplot` example is wrong! The values after ..., `-(10^1)`, `-(10^0)` should be `-(10^-1)`, `-(10^2)`....

Comment: No, that's what I want to achieve. I want to display large data ranges ( big negative numbers to +2), for which linear isn't appropriate, because it's beginning to get interesting around zero. Symlog stands for symmetric log. So it's a mirrored log scale around the x-axis

Comment: This is not implemented out of the box by `pgfplots`.

I think what you need is possible thanks to the `y coord trafo` feature detailed in the `pgfplots` manual, section **4.21 Symbolic Coordinates and User Transformations**

See also [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114796/116936), in a more simple situation (for x -> x^2 scaling).

Comment: As marsupilam already stated that is not supported yet. In fact, there is already a feature request for that in the [PGFPlots Tracker](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/feature-requests/47/).

Answer (score 15):

Here we go, using the `y coord trafo` key from `pgfplots`.

The `symlog` function is defined using the `tikzmath`.

It is the function [image]

For some reason, I can't seem to be able to plot a `tikzmath` function including `if` conditionals with `pgfplots`, hence the clumsiness of the `symlog` internals.

We also define the inverse transform `symexp` and feed it to the `y coord inv trafo` key, to be able to use the `axis coordinate system`.

It is the function 
[image]

### The code

producing the following output :

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\tikzmath
{
  function symlog(\x,\a){
    \yLarge = ((\x>\a) - (\x<-\a)) * (ln(max(abs(\x/\a),1)) + 1);
    \ySmall = (\x >= -\a) * (\x <= \a) * \x / \a ;
    return \yLarge + \ySmall ;
  };
  function symexp(\y,\a){
    \xLarge = ((\y>1) - (\y<-1)) * \a * exp(abs(\y) - 1) ;
    \xSmall = (\y>=-1) * (\y<=1) * \a * \y ;
    return \xLarge + \xSmall ;
  };
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\basis{1}
  \pgfplotsset
  {
    y coord trafo/.code={\pgfmathparse{symlog(#1,\basis)}\pgfmathresult},
    y coord inv trafo/.code={\pgfmathparse{symexp(#1,\basis)}\pgfmathresult},
    yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,int detect,precision=2},
}
  \begin{axis}
    [
      height=12cm,
      legend pos=north west,
      scaled ticks = base 10:0,
      domain = -5:5.5,
      ytick = {-100,-10, -1,0,1,10,100},
      minor ytick = {-90,-80,...,-20,-9,-8,...,-2,-.9,-.8,...,.9,2,3,...,9,20,30,...,90},
      tick label style = {fill=white, fill opacity=.7},
      yminorgrids = true,
      ymajorgrids = true,
      xmajorgrids = true,
      samples=200,
      axis lines=center,
    ]
    \addplot+ [mark=none] {x} ;
    \addplot+ [mark=none] {exp(x)} ;
    \addplot+ [mark=none] {-exp(-x)} ;
    \legend {$x$,$e^x$,$-e^{-x}$}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Cheers,